# Android String.format() Returns Question Mark (??)

Tags: android, string, file, integer, string-formatting

I have an app which downloads some files from internet. The source file name is dynamically generated depending on user selection. I use following method to create source file name. Note that `fileId` is an integer (1-99).

```
final String fileName = "file_" + String.format("%02d", fileId) + "_download.jpg";
```

The issue is I have seen some users are unable to download files (and of course they leave 1 start ratings :( ). When I check my server log I see some download requests came with file names like `file_??_download.jpg`. It looks like `String.format()` has returned `??` instead of two digit number.

I searched everywhere and could not find a solution for this. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this code? I could not even re-produce this error on any of my devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it instead:

`final String fileName = "file_" + String.format("%d", fileId) + "_download.jpg";`

or

`final String fileName = "file_" + fileId + "_download.jpg";`

if you really want only the two last digits, do it:

```
int formattedFileId = fileId % 100;
final String fileName = "file_" + (formattedFileId < 10 ? '0' : '') + String.format("%d", formattedFileId) + "_download.jpg";
```

or

```
int formattedFileId = fileId % 100;
final String fileName = "file_" + (formattedFileId < 10 ? '0' : '') + formattedFileId + "_download.jpg";
```

Comment: Hi Augusto, thank you for your answer. I have updated my app with your code. I will keep checking logs to see if this issue still exist before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

String.format will use the digits for the default locale which are not necessarily 0-9. Use the version that permits setting a locale, and pass in `Locale.ROOT`.

```
String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%02d", fileId)
```

Comment: Thanks Joni. What about using Locale.ENGLISH ? Is this gonna make any issue on non-english devices?

Comment: No, but it raises a question on why specifically "English" and not the generic root locale.